# Change DB from local to azure not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created MVC 5 project in visual studio 2013 which work against local DB
and its working as expected,now I want to replace the localDb(v11) with new DB which I have created in azure (same data structure) ,how should I do that ?
I guess that I need to replace the connection string with the server and DB name but since the connection string is too long I dont know what exactly should I remove and add,please assist .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Azure you can look at the front-screen for a Database and then click 'View SQL Database connection strings.' This will bring up a pop-up that shows you an ADO.Net connection string.

[image: Azure - Find Connection Strings]

Once you've got the Azure string you can insert it into you config file like so:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="<AZURE CONNECTION STRING>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

You can then configure that Azure DB server to allow connections from your local machine. This will enable you to connect to the database while running locally.

[image: Azure DB firewall]

Comment: HI Josh thanks voted up ,I took the ADO.net connection,should I add it or replace it ? in addition when I copy it to the add tag as is I have lot of errors ,what should I change in the format to accept it without errors...one of the errors is Server attribute is not allowed ...

Comment: Put the string from azure into the quoted section <AZURE CONNECTION STRING>. You need to put all of the text into the quotes. You'll also have to get the password for the database and allow connections from your local machine through the firewall. You can do that from the connection string pop-up (look at the bottom).

Comment: Do I need to create new tag <AZURE CONNECTION STRING> and add it to it since I dont find any tag with this name...Can you please provide example?

Comment: You'll need to replace your existing connection string. There won't be an '<AZURE CONNECTION STRING>' tag in your config file. That was just an example. You can use the entire 'add' tag from above as your new connection string. Just replace the bits with specifics for your environment.

Comment: Thanks I'll just replace it as you suggested and publish to check it ,the only thing that I need to provide in addition is just the password ,correct? if I run it on the local now I got error because I have changed the connection string ,how should I avoid it?

Comment: You can either connect to the Azure DB from local by allowing connections from your local IP to the Azure DB in the DB firewall rules (this is done from the DB server config, not the database config). Another option is to use environment specific config files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx. Don't forget to mark as the answer, thanks!

Comment: HI Josh ,hope this is the last question ,how should I verify that I put the connection string right ?currently the publish was finished and I got error when I click on the link of service "error while processing your request ).I took you connection string and put it as-is in the azure tag and add password ...

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=tcp:vqrs.database.windows.net,1473;Database=serveri34;User ID=Jean;Password=welcome1;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Above I posted the exact connection string which I use can you please see if someting wrong,Im stuck with it...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the string that you posted. I've added a screenshot for setting firewall rules on your Azure DB server. That will allow you to connect to the DB from your local machine. Otherwise, can you post the error that you're seeing?

Comment: When I Open the firewall Ruls I see ip num provided by default but this is not my desktop IP ,what should I put there ? 2 .where should I see the error log in the cloud currently I got error in the browser http 500,Thanks you very much for your support :)

Comment: The IP you need to use is your IP as it looks to the internet. You can go to this site: http://www.whatismyip.com/. Make sure that IP can go through the firewall.

Comment: Thank you very much Josh for your support! I saw this exact IP ,but it still not working for me ,I got HTTP500 there is a way somehow to see the log and error to see what is the problem?

Comment: in addition where should I put the azure db name?

Comment: Jean, try this set of articles. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951633.aspx